# How to read register of digital counter with minimalmodbus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, rs485, minimalmodbus

I'm trying to read the values of an industry digital counter with Modbus RTU RS-485. Using USB-RS-485 conversion, and here is the master send code is taken from the following datasheet,

[Datasheet Link](https://www.autonicsonline.com/image/pdf/CT.pdf)

[image: Snippets from Autonics CT series datasheet]

I am expecting that the read input register is what I'm expecting, and the API of the minimalmodbus expects to specify register number, a number of decimals, and function code.

- Does the library auto-assign the slave number, or we have to define it?
- From the datasheet, is it the register number is the address?
- And how many decimals do I expect if there's two data sequence as a response?
- Is the CRC16 check already included within the library as i shouldn't code it?

Here's my code by far, modifying examples.

```
import minimalmodbus
import time

# port name, slave address (in decimal)
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)

instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600      
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 1          
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU  
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
instrument.debug = True

while True:
    # Register number, number of decimals, function code
    # not sure what to expect on number of register, is it 31004, 31005?
    
    digit_count = instrument.read_register(1, 2, 4)
    print(digit_count)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have read other libraries for python Modbus, I would be happy to get any better coding recommendation related to Modbus. Thank you in prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the library auto-assign the slave number, or we have to define it?

With [MinimalModbus](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-multiple-instruments) you pass the slave ID through in the `minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)` call (the 1 is the Slave ID). How you set the slave ID on the device itself varies (this is not covered by the [Modbus over serial line spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf); could be a configuration program, DIP switches, based on the serial number etc. Other libraries may take different approaches (for example defaulting to Slave ID 1).

> From the datasheet, is it the register number is the address?

The header in the spec tables says "No(Address)" so "10001(0000)" means register 1, address 0 (these refer to the same thing; I recommend reading the "Modbus: When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" section in [this article](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html) which explains some of the issues around addressing).

> And how many decimals do I expect if there's two data sequence as a response?

Not quite sure what you mean by "two data sequence". The [Modbus spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) only details the sending of bits (coils) and 16 bit values (input/holding registers). From a quick look at your spec it looks like this device just uses a single registers; for instance "OUT1 Output time" has "unit: ×10㎳" so take whatever is in the register and divide by 10 to get ms.

> Is the CRC16 check already included within the library as i shouldn't code it?

Any decent Modbus library will look after the protocol details (such as CRC) for you (so no you don't need to code this; [MinimalModbus will calculate](https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/master/minimalmodbus.py#L3163) it for you)

Comment: Thank you, by data sequence i meant two data from the response from the image i provided, i assume it's 2 bytes if i'm not wrong (E2 40 00 01 in H) - how to get the data of  E2 40 00 01 ? I am still confused since on the docs, the master requires to send a query to the specified register, which is a bit different than the code? or does the library will manage to send query if we specify function code is 4?  Say i want to fetch information from No -> 31004, does it simply the number register is 4 to put on the argument (or 31004?).

Comment: Minimal modbus will handle most of this for you (`read_register` returns a 16 bit integer; the library deals with processing the detail for you). The library will send the query and process the response into something usable. For minimal modbus you are passing the address so 31004 = `read_register(1003,0,3,true)` (note it looks like "Present value
of counter/timer" may be split over two registers but the document is not clear on this).

Comment: Thank you for the response that's very clear. Yes i believe it is split to two 31004 31005 register and probably i will have to combine them later and do hex to decimal conversion. I assume 1003 is 03EB in decimal, therefore : `read_register(1003,0,3,true)` and `read_register(1004,0,3,true)` . However why does function code that you written is 3, since from the datasheet is 4? Sorry for the redundant question

Comment: Sorry you are correct `read_register(1004,0,4,true)` (answered on phone). Found the bit in the spec re combining the registers "31004 : Present Value(Low Word), 31005 : Present Value(High Word)" so you can use `read_long(1003, 4, true, BYTEORDER_LITTLE)` to read this (the library will combine the values for you). "hex to decimal conversion" not sure why you feel this is needed (the Modbus functions will return a number - hex/dec only comes into play when you need to display this).

Comment: That is very clear indeed, thank you for the clarification of the function code. And yes i thought the return value would be in hex, such as "03H" or anything, i just want the data in integers or decimal perhaps, just to send value to the datacenter.